# $ \lim_{x \to 0} \cos^{-1}(1-x)/\sqrt x$

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^{-1}(1-x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
  $$=\frac{\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$$
$$=1$$

But answer is $\sqrt2$ .. why this is so...

Comment: How did you get the first equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Let $\cos^{-1}(1-x)=2y,0\le2y\le\pi$

$1-x=\cos2y\implies x=1-\cos2y\implies\sqrt x=\sqrt2\sin y$ as $0\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

Answer (score 2):

Use L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^{-1}(1-x)}{\sqrt{x}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}\cdot (-1)}{\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2-x}}=\sqrt{2}.$$

Comment: What is wrong in my approach

Comment: @AbhishekKumar your attempt is not clear.

Comment: it must be: $\cos^{-1} (1-x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1}(1-x)$ or $\cos^{-1} (1-x)=\sin^{-1}\sqrt{2x-x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\theta=\cos^{-1}(1-x)$, then $\cos\theta=1-x$, so $\sin^2\theta=1-(1-x)^2=2x-x^2\sim 2x$, i.e., $\sin\theta\sim\sqrt{2x}$, not $\sin\theta\sim\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 0):

Use L'Hopital's Rule,
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos^{-1} (1-x^2)}{\sqrt x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{1-x^2}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sqrt x}{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}=\sqrt 2$$